# Cannot get image to show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a modal window to display images. I want to add right and left arrow click images over the modal window but having issues getting it to show.

Here is my code:

Here we create the dimmer (modal window). `newelement` is an internal function that creates DOM Elements. In this case, we create the dimmer element, append it to the document.body, and then apply some styles shorthand (backgound-color,opacity,transition)

```
var dimmer=newelement("div",document.body,"bgc=#101010;op=0;tr=0.15s ease in");
dimmer.id="dimmer";
```

Now, I want to add a right click image to the dimmer. I have a fixed position with the left at 70%, top at 50%, added a box-shadow, z-index at 10003 and an opacity of 0.

```
var rclickimage=newelement("img",document.body,"p=f;l=70%;t=50%;bx=0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z=10003;op=0");
rclickimage.src='/img/007359-blue-jelly-icon-arrows-arrow-thick-right.png';
```

Finally, here is the image itself that gets rendered. **You'll notice here that the left is at 50% whereas the right click image starts at 70%** This element has a fixed position with the left at 50%, top at 50%, added a box-shadow, z-index at 10003 and an opacity of 0.

```
image=newelement("img",document.body,"p=f;l=50%;t=50%;bx=0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z=10003;op=0");
image.src="/services/attachment/"+mediaid+"/"+window.innerWidth+"x"+window.innerHeight;
```

Here is the onload function that gets called when the `image` loads:

```
image.onload=function(e) {
  this.onload=null;
  var ml=parseInt(this.width/2); var mt=parseInt(this.height/2);
  //margin left and margin top (ml and mt)
  setstyle(this,"ml=-"+ml+"px;mt=-"+mt+"px");
  animate(this,"opacity",1,0.2);  
   if (dimmer.spinner) { document.body.removeChild(dimmer.spinner);dimmer.spinner=0; }
}
```

So thats it. **Everything works great except getting the right click image to display**

Comment: how do yo handle the right click event?

Comment: @Nicholas i dont see why this is important. My issue is that i cannot get the image to display within the modal window i created.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @jkushner To me it looks like you're creating the image with opacity of 0 and never change that to 1. I won't post this as an answer until you respond. It's tough to tell for sure without seeing more code or a live example.

Comment: @SergChernata That solved it thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this line you're creating an image that has 0 opacity. You don't seem to be changing that to opacity of 1 at any point thereafter.

```
image=newelement("img",document.body,"p=f;l=50%;t=50%;bx=0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z=10003;op=0");
```